# Customized log notation

Tags: spacing, math-operators

In my country, the base of logarithm is written in superscript before the log sign, i.e. `$^a\log b$` means log base `a` of `b`. This doesn't look nice on LaTeX, because there is a gap between `^a` and `\log`. How to remove this gap?

Comment: I've never seen that notation and I find it a source for ambiguities, even if there's a thin space before the superscript: $2\mylog{2}x$ (with David's definition) will leave the reader with the doubt whether it's "four times the logarithm of x" or "2 times the base 2 logarithm of x".

Comment: Indeed it is. Unfortunately I have no choice but to follow the consensus.

For such case of ambiguity, I'd put a dot to indicate multiplication.

Comment: Can you reveal where this notation is used? It's certainly uncommon.

Comment: I'm from Indonesia

Comment: This is not an uncommon notation at all. Here in the Netherlands it is also widely used. It is taught like this at the middle school.

Comment: Indeed this is quite common in The Netherland. The downside of this notation is indeed the ambiguity when writing 2 ^3log x  (which can be avoided with a $\cdot$. The upside is that it is easier to verbalise as "three log x", because you can keep reading left to right. Same goes for writing it down.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a negative space `\!` to remove (or reduce) this to your liking. It would be best to define a command for this, for the sake of consistency:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse
\NewDocumentCommand{\Log}{o}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}{}{{}^{#1}\!}\log}%
\begin{document}
\[
  {}^a\log xyz\ \mbox{or}\ \Log[a]xyz\ \mbox{or}\ \Log xyz\ \mbox{or}\ \log_a xyz
\]
\end{document}​
```

Of course, more specific kerning is also possible using `\kern`.

The above MWE defined `\Log[<base>]` that takes an optional argument `<base>`. Without `<base>` it defaults to `\log`.

Answer (score 10):

[image]

The space comes because `\log` is a `\mathop` command. Here you don't want any space between the superscript and the `log` but you *do* want the entire construct to be a `\mathop` so:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\mylog[1]{\mathop{{}^{#1}\mathrm{log}}}

\begin{document}


$ x+x\mylog2 x$
\end{document}​
```

Comment: The downside to this method seems to be that te base is not typset in mathfont. For instance, the "g" in `\mylog{g}` will look different from `$g$`.

Comment: I found a quick solve by using `{}\textsuperscript{$#1$}`

Comment: @gebruiker never use `\textsuperscript` in math: if you want the superscript in the same font as `log` then simply specify it in the same way, change `#1` to `\mathrm{#1}` Oh no you say you _want_ the base to be in a math font. That is what my original definition does.